# Static reference to non-static field Java error

Tags: java, static, reference, stack, non-static

I'll preface this by saying that I've been a longtime fan of Stack Overflow, and over the past few semesters I've usually been able to find the answer to all my questions without actually asking one. However, I've been having problems with a stack program. There's more code than this, but I think I've narrowed my problem down to this one error. It states

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
> problems:
>
> > Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field Stack1
> > The constructor Stack(int) is undefined
>
> at stack.main(stack.java:11)

Can anyone explain what the issue might be? Or better yet, point me to somewhere that will explain it? I've tried looking it up on Overflow and through google, but I think a combination of not knowing what I'm actually looking for and/or fatigue is preventing me from finding a concrete answer. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
public class stack {
private Object[] Stack1;
private int topOfStack;
private int max;
//private int empty;
//private int capacity;

public static void main(String[] args) {
Stack1 = new Stack(5);
    
}

public Stack(int size) {
    if (size < 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter must be >0. Parameter was " + size + ".");
    }
    
    max = size; 
    Stack1 = (Object[]) (new Object[size]);
    topOfStack = -1;
}
   }
```

Comment: You need a little reorganization of your code. What is it you're trying to achieve? Do you just want to create a Stack object to have available?

Comment: Please fix your style and indentation! this is Java so class names should begin with an uppercase ("Stack" not "stack"), variable names and method names should begin with a lowercase ("stack1" not "Stack1"). Notice the colouring in the code here on SO - identifiers beginning with a capital are coloured differently because they are assumed to be types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your class "Stack" (uppercase) and change the line:

```
Stack1 = new Stack(5)
```

to:

```
Stack stack1 = new Stack(5);
```

Comment: so simple! I had tried Stack stack1 = new Stack(int) initially but changed it, only to see that the class name was wrong! So disappointed in myself. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. We all have "Oh, duh" moments. Sometimes just takes another set of eyes ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the following line -

```
private Object[] Stack1;
```

`Stack1` is not **static**.

And in the following you are trying to refer to `Stack1` -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack1 = new Stack(5);
}
```

from within `main` which is **static**.

Thus -

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field Stack1

Your constructor name is `Stack` which does not match  class name is `stack`. So -

> The constructor Stack(int) is undefined

May be, you want to name your class `Stack` and in your `main` the following -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack stack1 = new Stack(5);
}
```

Comment: You'll also need to change stack1 to not be an object array.

Comment: @RachelG.: What should it be?

Comment: Nevermind. I was thinking you were setting the class variable "Stack1". Was an Object[] getting set to a Stack. But you created a new stack1 local variable. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Your class is declared as `stack` lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

`Stack1` is in instance variable to the `stack` class.  In your static main method, you try to store a value in the `Stack1` variable even though it is an instance variable.  Also, you try to assign a non-array type to a variable whose type is an *array* of `Object`.  Furthermore, you have a constructor for `Stack` (note the uppercase) even though the class is called `stack` in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the lower case class declaration, I'm guessing the assignment

```
   Stack1 = new Stack(5);
```

is not what you meant.  Rather:

```
Stack1 stack = new stack(5);
```